# Footer not sticking to the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a footer that will remain at the botoom even if the content in the body is not able to fill the browser viewport. I do not want it to overlap over the main body content when the height of the content is enough to fill the viewport. On searching online I mostly find a "sticky" footer which overlaps with the content even the content is enough to fill up the viewport. So far, this is what I am trying (I am also using bootstrap3)

HTML (within the `<body>` tag):

```
<footer style="background-color: #b77b48;color:white;padding:10px">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-4">
<h4 class="text-center"> About</h4>
<p class="text-justify">This website is blah bah</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<h4 class="text-center">Links</h4> 
<p class="text-center">
<a href=# style="color:white">Rules & FAQ</a><br />
<a href=# style="color:white">Privacy Policy</a><br />
<a href=# style="color:white">Contact Us</a><br />
<a href=# style="color:white">Other Projects</a><br />
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<h4 class="text-center">Find us at</h4> 
<p style="text-align: center;"><i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" ></i> &nbsp;
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i> &nbsp;
<i class="fa fa-youtube fa-3x"></i>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
```

CSS:

```
 body,html{
 min-height:100%;
}
.container{
 /*min-height:20%;*/
}
footer{
 height:180px;
 bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: when you say "I do not want it to overlap over the main body content when the height of the content is enough to fill the viewport" do you mean at no point should the footer ever cover the body content? that the scrollbar for the body content should end at the top of the footer?

Comment: added answers for both :)

Answer (score 2):

I think would be useful for you to read this article:

http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/

You can also check this friddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/giovapanasiti/atCUX/

```
$(function() {
    // Store references to all rows for future use
    var rows = $(".Row"),
        content = rows.filter(".Expand");

    // Test first to see if `display: table;` is being used
    if (rows.css("display") === "block") {
        function reflow() {
            var height = rows.parent().height();
            // Subtract height of fixed rows
            rows.not(content).each(function() {
                height -= $(this).height();
            });
            content.height(height);
        }
        // Run immediately on DOM ready…
        reflow();
        // And again on page load and resize events
        $(window).bind("load resize", reflow);
    }
});
```

(it is not all made by me. I forked it years ago and cannot remember where i took it)

Comment: this doesnt appear to work when the content is really long.. http://jsfiddle.net/atCUX/1/ at least not in terms of creating a 'sticky' footer

Comment: Sorry maybe i didnt get it. I thought he need a way to not have the footer on half page when contents were too short.

Comment: :) ah i getcha.. yeah i think that was just part of the problem.. nice solution with `display:table;` not sure the js is 100% necessary though :)

Comment: looks like you were correct in your interpretation of 'sticky' navigation haha +1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the footer is at the bottom of the HTML, I need to see more of the HTML to see why it wont shift to the bottom, all you are showing is the footer itself. Try a div instead of the footer tag, just an idea

Answer (score 1):

you need to look at adding the following to your css:

`position:fixed` and then giving your `body` some `padding-bottom` to match the height of the `<footer>`

I read your question in 1 of 2 ways

1) here is a jsfiddle example that will mean the footer is always locked to the bottom of the page and the body content will scroll behind it http://jsfiddle.net/S4Qpa/3/

2) here is a jsfiddle example that will mean the footer is always locked to the bottom of the page and the body content will scroll in the space remaining above it http://jsfiddle.net/S4Qpa/2/

one issue with 2) is that you may find you encounter weird issues with mobile touch scrolling, so i would definitely recommend the first one

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me a footer that although sticks to the bottom, it does so even when there the body content is long enough. i.e it never leaves the browser viewport and I have to scroll down to view the hidden/overlapped body content. To give an example, I want something live the StackOVerflow footer.

Comment: oh..well if that's the case then you want @Giova-panasiti's answer