# CSS background color wrapper (Cause by mistake)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, wrapper, background-color

I have meet a interesting problem here.
my structure is

```
body
|----site-wrapper
       |-----cover-wrapper
```

both the height is set to 100%, when I set the `site-wrapper` background color, it looks fine,
but when I set `cover-wrapper` background color, it only wrapper the background color to fit the content(some text), not expand to the whole screen, I have tried both on Chrome and Firefox.  check the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/h82Ne/

Here is the css:

```
html{
    height: 200%
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

.site-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%; /* For at least Firefox */
    min-height: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.cover-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: have a look at this answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22716804/648350

Comment: Your fiddle differs from the code here.

Comment: @skip405 yes, I miss one class here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the `.cover-wrapper` to cover the entire page you can use:

```
.cover-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

This will cause it to act more like an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved, it make by my own mistake, i miss css for site-wrapper-inner here.

Sorry about that